# inequality involving integrals and $n$ square roots

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

can i say that, if $M>0$ ^and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\displaystyle\left (\int_{-M}^{M} x^n \right)^{1/n} \leq\displaystyle\int_{-M}^{M} x$?

Comment: is it $x^n dx $.

Comment: the right hand side is zero if you are integrating in $x$

Comment: For $n$ even your LHS is positive while RHS is zero. For $n$ odd, both sides are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Rather, we have $\left(M^{-1}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{M}x^{1/n}dx\right)^{n}\leq M^{-1}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{M}xdx$, this is known as Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $x\rightarrow x^{n}$, $n\geq 1$.